# Laravel. ide helper. composer

Tags: laravel, composer

```
Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[dev-master, v2.9.0] require illuminate/console ^8 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper 2.9.x-dev is an alias of barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
    - Root composer.json requires barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ^2.9 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.9.0, 2.9.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
```

вопросов особено нет, просьба не минусовать просто так. не понимаю что тут написано:не может потому что конфликтует сам с собой?

Answer (score 1):

У меня были такие же проблемы. Перерыл весь интернет, в итоге вот: при установке пакета, укажите его более раннюю версию.

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper:2.5.0
```

И это помогло (Laravel 5.6)